# comparing current time while reading given directories in textfile

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to read a stage.txt and list all files older than 10 mins but somehow my output is repeating and didn't echo the correct lines with old timing. Is there possible way to retain and print value since i already manipulated the data with awk?

`/tmp/stage.txt`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:31 /opt/4.txt
```

Code:

```
##current time = 15:40
while IFS= read -r line
do
    diffstg="10"
    timeminstg=`echo $line |awk -F" " '{print $8}'|sed 's/://g'` ## getting the time each line##
    timediffstg=$((10#$timeHH$timeMM - 10#$timeminstg)) ## 15:40 - 15:20 and so on
    if [ "$timediffstg" -ge "$diffstg" ] 
    then
        echo $datetoday > $email
        echo  ${line} >> $email
    else
        echo "Nothing older than 10 mins"
    fi
done < /tmp/stage.txt
```

wrong output I am getting: if used $datetoday > $email

```
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:31 /opt/4.txt
```

wrong output I am getting: if used $datetoday >> $email - somehow correct output but the date is repeating.

```
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/1.txt
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/2.txt
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/3.txt
```

expected output:

```
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/3.txt
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is generally a bad idea. Use the `stat` command to get the file's modification time as a number, and compare that to a numeric timestamp.

Comment: Each time through the loop you're clearing the file with `echo $datetoday > $email`. That should use `>>` instead of `>`. Or you can put `> "$email"` after `done` to have all the loop's output written to the file.

Comment: Why are you doing the comparisons in `bash`? You should be able to do the entire thing in `awk`.

Comment: Using `find /path/to/files -newermt '<some date>'` is also an option to avoid manually calculating de time difference.

Comment: i'm somehow getting correct output now but echoing date output multiple times.. I tried both > and >> but still included in loop
##
  then
        echo $datetoday >> $email ##if single > it will print only last line
        echo  ${line} >> $email
output: 
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/1.txt
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/2.txt
Sun Apr  9 15:40:10 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/3.txt

Comment: not checking the actual directories in system but the directories is inside a file so i need to read it there. thanks

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Answer (score -1):

You can use some variable to know, if it is your first time reporting file or not. If it is first time, echo the header first (with single > to override target) and set, that it is not first time anymore. Anyway echo the file (with double >> so it appends to target).

Something like this

```
##current time = 15:40
firstline=1
while IFS= read -r line
do
    diffstg="10"
    timeminstg=`echo $line |awk -F" " '{print $8}'|sed 's/://g'` ## getting the time each line##
    timediffstg=$((10#$timeHH$timeMM - 10#$timeminstg)) ## 15:40 - 15:20 and so on
    if [ "$timediffstg" -ge "$diffstg" ] 
    then
        if [ "$firstline" == "1" ]
        then
                echo first $firstline
                firstline=0
                echo $datetoday > $email
        fi    
        echo  ${line} >> $email
    else
        echo "Nothing older than 10 mins"
    fi
done < /tmp/stage.txt
```

and the output in $email should look like

```
Sun Apr  9 20:57:28 CEST 2023
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3046 Apr 9 15:20 /opt/3.txt
```